# segmentation fault (core dumped) in C programming

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I am currently studying data structures and algorithms and learning how stacks works.

I wrote a simple C code that shows how the basic functionalities of stacks works including `push` and `pop` algorithm which basically process elements into an array. The code wasn't finish yet and I am trying to learn the language and its algorithm as day goes by. To my surprise I've received an error `'segmentation fault (core dumped)'` after compiling and it's pretty confusing for me as an individual who is learning how to code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100

struct stack
{
  int a[MAXSIZE];
  int Top;
};

/*
 * Add an element to stack
 */
void push(struct stack *pu)
{
  int element;

  printf("element: ");
  scanf(" %d", &element);
  pu->a[pu->Top] = element;

  if(pu->a[pu->Top] >= MAXSIZE -1)
     {
        printf("stack is full\n");
 } else{
        // Prints out the top most element
    printf("Top is: %d\n", pu->a[pu->Top]); 
 }
}

/*
* Pop/Remove an element from the stack
*/
void pop(struct stack *po)
{
  printf("You're in pop function.\n");
     if(po->Top <= -1)
    {
       printf("stack is underflow");
    } else{
       printf("%d will be remove from the stack", po->a[po->Top]);
       printf("%d has been removed from the stack", po->a[po->Top]);
    }
}
void Second(char x[])
{
  struct stack pa;

     if(x[1] == 'u')
    {
           push(&pa);
     } else if(x[1] == 'o'){
       pop(&pa);
     }
}   

int main()
{
  int element;

     char s[MAXSIZE];
     struct stack ps;   
     ps.Top = -1; 

     printf("Push or Pop?\n");
 scanf("%s", &s);

 Second(s);    
}
```

Comment: Here `pu->a[pu->Top] >= MAXSIZE -1` you are comparing the top value with the maximum size. I think you wanted to compare current size with maximum size

Comment: You are right, if Top value exceeds MAXSIZE which is set at 100 it'll print "stack is full"

Comment: You stack is full when one pushes a single element (with value 100), but your stack never gets full when you only push values <100. Either magic or wrong ;)

Comment: You have a point, I'll look more into it. Haven't paid attention to that

Comment: Your `pop` function does nothing except for some `printf`s. Shouldn't it remove the element?

Comment: Hint: use hard coded test data, it's much easier to test and to debug. Also don't mix data processing and input, for example: push should accept the data to push and not do a scanf inside the push function. The best is probably to throw that code away and start over properly.

Comment: What do you expect the value of the field *Top* to be in this statement: `pu->a[pu->Top] = element;`? Try to print it before this statement.

Comment: The fundamental problem I see is that while you are declaring and initializing a `stack` structure in `main()` you also declare one in `Second()`. It’s uninitialized, so the `Top` element is undefined. Using it in `push()` and `pop()` is UB.

Comment: Actually about everything than can be made wrong is wrong in this code. 1. mixing input and data processing. 2. Poor naming  3. interactive input for testing/debugging which is painful. 4. Two different stacks, one in second and one in main. 5. pop doesn't do anything. 6. The test if stack is full is totally wrong. And probably a few more problems. Throw that code away. Then start with a piece of paper and a pencil. Then rewrite your code taking into account the comments.

Answer (score 1):

## You are accessing an illegal address

To answer your question specifically, the issue is in the function `void Second(char[])` : you didn't initialized `struct stack pa`. `pa.Top` take some unpredictable value, most likely much too big, and you try to access a memory space not reserved in `push` when you do `pu->a[pu->Top] = element;`. Trying to access a memory address not reserved by your process results in a segmentation fault (segfault).

Doing `pa->a[99999] = whatever` would propably segfault too, because `pa->a` as a size of `100` as defined in snippet.

## Initializing a struct

When declaring a variable, or a struct, such as your stack, you are only declaring that you will need the memory to use that object. But, you do not specifically ask for that memory to be filled with values that makes sens. Usually, that means that the struct is set with whatever data was already in memory from previous use. This is why you should set the fields of your struct to known values as soon as possible. How you do so is a matter of style, I usually make a function dedicated to that named `mystruct_ctor` (for constructor) or just set everything to zero with `struct stack pa = {0}` .